# How to pass the data correctly inside a ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Well i have a viewpager for displaying images slides. Now when i get the images from the drawable folder and pass the array to the adapter it's work fine.. but i want to get those images from json file i have a json file in which i have images link now i don't know how to pass images from json file in a form of array to viewpager adapter and display it. thanks in advance

article is my model class which get the json data

```
Article article;
ImageView imageView;
viewpagerAdapter adapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
int[] im;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poraimage);
    viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter=new viewpagerAdapter(poraimage.this,how can i  pass my model class in array here);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

   Context context;
int [] imageViews;
LayoutInflater inflater;

viewpagerAdapter(Context contexts,int[] image){
    this.imageViews=image;
    this.context=contexts;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageViews.length;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==((LinearLayout) object);
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpageritem,container,false);
    ImageView imageView=v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageViews[position]);
    container.addView(v);
    return v;

}





    {
  "data":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/31/48/3d/31483da5d71b46e202fb19fbfff02b17--hairstyles-men-mens-haircuts.jpg"
    },
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "data1":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "data2":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this

use only data for images

```
     {
      "data":[
        {
          "linkimage":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/31/48/3d/31483da5d71b46e202fb19fbfff02b17--hairstyles-men-mens-haircuts.jpg"
        },
        {
          "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
        }
{
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
{
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
      ],
    }
```

read that data from jsonfile

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("file_name.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

   ArrayList<ModelClass> list = new ArrayList();
     viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

read the string which return by the above method

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset);
JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for(int i =0;i<m_jArry.size;i++){
            ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
            model.setImageUrl(json.getString("linkimage");
            list.add(model);
            }
```

and pass this list to adapter

```
  adapter=new viewpagerAdapter(this,list);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your Adapter

```
Context context;
ArrayList<ModelClass>list;
LayoutInflater inflater;

viewpagerAdapter(Context contexts,ArrayList<ModelClass>list){
    this.list=list;
    this.context=contexts;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageViews.length;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==((LinearLayout) object);
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpageritem,container,false);
    ImageView imageView=v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_image);
    ModelClass model = list.get(position);
//Use libaray to show image like picasso glide etc.

Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImageUrl)
               .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).into(mImageDownloader);

    container.addView(v);
    return v;

}
```

Comment: Hey bunny thanksalot for your answer but how can i get json array?

Comment: {
  "data":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/31/48/3d/31483da5d71b46e202fb19fbfff02b17--hairstyles-men-mens-haircuts.jpg"
    },
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "data1":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "data2":[
    {
      "linkimage":"https://dresseskhazana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Butch-Haircut-3-300x300.jpg"
    }
  ]}

Comment: this is my json file

Comment: and also i have upload it

Comment: why data1 data2 ?

Comment: data 1 is for position one and data 2 is for position second

Comment: you showing image only in viewpager or something else

Comment: i dont understand why data1 data2 when you can manage this only using data

Comment: i can't understand how to do this?

Comment: the adapter getting the images length but not showing